# For Each Loop stops after deleting one row

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am trying to use an if else statement to delete the entire row when a text value is found in a cell within a given range.

The code stops after deleting one row.

```vb
Sub DeleteSpecificRow()
    Set RR = Range("C1:C8")
    For Each cell In RR
        If cell.Value = "Site subcode " Or cell.Value = "Sample type" Or cell.Value = "Lab Sample ID code" Or cell.Value = "name determinand" Then cell.EntireRow.Delete
    Next cell
End Sub
```

I tried without using CELL at the end of the next but had the same affect.

Comment: Are there many occurrences of such strings in the processed range? If so, the code will not stop after the first occurrence. Anyhow, if you intend processing a much larger range, it is recommended to use a `Union` range, set and build during iteration and delete each rows at the code end, at once. It will make the code much faster.

Comment: In order to check your supposition, try running the code line by line, pressing `F8`... And move the cursor over each `cell` variable to see each value.

Comment: When deleting rows, always loop from the bottom row up to the top row

Answer (score 1):

Try to loop in reverse, because if row is deleted address of all rows below also changes, which result your RR range obsolete and code stops. (e.g. if row 3 is deleted, row 4 becomes the new row 3, while your RR range points to the old address.)

```
Sub DeleteSpecificRow()
    Set RR = Range("C1:C8")
    With RR
        For i = .cells.count to 1 step -1
            If .cells(i).Value = "Site subcode " Or .cells(i).Value = "Sample type" Or .cells(i).Value = "Lab Sample ID code" Or .cells(i).Value = "name determinand" Then .cells(i).EntireRow.Delete
        Next
    End with
End Sub
```

Comment: That is extremely helpful and works perfectly. Just a clarification but is that why you use the i variable to reset the address within the For statement instead of how it becoming null if it you simply used RR (per this example?)

Comment: @Hecytor For i is only used for looping from down to up and that solves the issue. Because references of the rows above the deleted row are not changed.